# cannot open new project flutter wizard android studio bumblebee 2021.1.1

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

hello i am beginner in flutter, i want ask

i cant create project flutter, how to fix this?

i have all check in flutter doctor
[flutter doctor image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCFPy.png)

and already install dart and flutter in android studio
[plugin image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a1ZP.png)

and then android support already enable to
[android support image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcKyX.png)

so what i must do? because i cant make new flutter project
[make flutter project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTnIY.png)

Comment: had you restart studio after installing flutter plugin?

Comment: yes i did @Avinash, i already reinstall to, but its still same

Comment: as of now an alternative option you can use cmd

Answer (score 0):

When you making the flutter project you can't make it without flutter SDK path.(Path which you installed the flutter directory). if you didn't
installed it, first install it.

- Browse the folder path of flutter SDK
- Select the folder path

for more details,
[Click the link - Flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#android-setup)

Comment: i already install and set the path of flutter, if i select the path on android studio, its can crete flutter project, but still not showing project type like when i want to create android project